# How to create two search bar in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, xcode7.3

I am new in programming, I search how to create two search bars in swift in one page like search bar in google maps in the picture (sample version):

[image: picture]

Can anybody give me some idea to find a solution or any tutorials or references ?

Comment: Just curious are you making mapping type application? If you are then use two text fields like good4pc said below otherwise it seems like bad design to have 2 search bars in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextfields for implementing the search bar as shown in the figure and use the delegate method to get the text and process it according to your need.You can use  tags to recognize the textfields.

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    //your code
}
```

Hope this helps you.